# Bathroom Remodel Drain/Vent Configuration

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, vent

All, thank you in advance for the help.

I am remodeling a bathroom and fall under IPC 2018 and was hoping that folks could look over the design below and let me know if this was code compliant and if follows good practice. Basically I was wondering if the proposed layout worked as a wet vent system or if I needed to open the wall and run new individual vents. Any suggestions are welcome.

photos at links below

Current Configuration - https://drive.google.com/open?id=18laXLjQdX7CR97IxsfdHEKBLSG1uoDaW

Proposed Configuration - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oLorrhJ4ObA_jmICtfHLMOnkeN7k6Qa3

As is photo - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SCymslJ1p0Cx1zQNjvSOqe7A5Wa7zjMW

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the sink is technically being individually vented back to the 3" vent is throwing me off.

I don't have a copy of the IPC 2018 code and I'm in Canada, but I believe the codes are similar.

Is there any way to extend the 3" portion closer to the sink so that you can still run the fixture arm with only 135° change in direction? You can then offset the vent back to the existing location once 6" above the flood level rim of the sink:

[image: sugested alterations]

With the above alteration, this would be a clear wet vent.

A few additional notes:

- The fall on the fixture trap arm can not exceed that of the diameter of the pipe. So for 1-1/2" run with 2% grade the max length would be 6' and 2" pipe would be 8'.
- A fixture trap arm cannot exceed 135° change in direction (except for a toilet which cannot exceed 225°).
- The length of the wet vent is not limited.
- A toilet must be the last fixture in a wet vent (or connected with a symmetrical fitting).